# Routing: How to apply routes to all Domains except one

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

I have an application listening to three types of subdomain:

1. Main application: *www.website.com*
2. Custom subdomains handled by the same logic as the main application: **.app.website.com*
3. Admin panel: *backend.website.com*

### Setup

The custom subdomains are coming in from a wildcard subdomain and managed by a Laravel middleware, which checks the database for validity and routes to *www.website.com* if an unknown subdomain request is coming in.

Otherwise the app behaves a little different on **.app.website.com* here and there, but is mainly the same as the main application.

The requests on *backend.website.com* should be namespaced.

This setup mostly is working just fine.

### Problem

The routes of the main application are accessible via the *backend.website.com* subdomain. I want the admin routes to only take the routes inside its group into account.

I tried to seperate the route groups by domain with the wildcard, but this will pass the wildcard as the first parameter to all controller actions, which is undesirable. I don’t need the wildcard at all, since this will be checked and handled by the middleware.

### What I’ve tried

```
Route::domain('backend.website.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        …
    });
});


$appRoutes = function() {
    // this should not be hit by backend.website.com
    Route::get('/', function () {
        …
    })->name('home');

    …
};

Route::domain('www.website.com')->group($appRoutes);

// would probably work but passes $account to all 
// controller actions as first parameter which is undesirable
Route::domain('{account}.app.website.com')->group($appRoutes);
```

I’m hoping to be clear enough and would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooray, I think I found the answer only minutes after asking. Please correct me, if that’s bullshit.

#### Routes

```
Route::domain(config('app.admin_url'))->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        …
    });
});


$appRoutes = function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        …
    })->name('home');
    …
};

// the middleware will redirect all requests from subdomains it does not know
// to the main application anyway, so trying to request main application routes 
// via backend.website.com will be redirected – yes!

Route::middleware(['\App\Http\Middleware\CheckSiteDomain'])->group($appRoutes);
```

#### CheckSiteDomain Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $url = url('');

    $app_url_regex = preg_quote(config('app.url'), '/');

    if (!preg_match("/^$app_url_regex/i", $url)) {

        // if current subdomain does not equal main application domain
        // try to find a matching "site" in the database and 
        // redirect if none is found

        $site = Site::byUrl($url, true);

        if (!$site)
            return redirect(config('app.url'));

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Thanks anyway! Sorry, I always struggle a long time before asking – probably even longer next time. ;-)

Comment: Your fast question solved my problem, so not be sorry. Thank you for posting the solution!